# Can I make return type vary with parameter a bit like sprintf in F#?

Tags: f#

In the F# core libraries there are functions whose signature seemingly changes based on the parameter at compile-time:

```ml
> sprintf "Hello %i" ;; 
val it : (int -> string) = <fun:it@1>

> sprintf "Hello %s" ;; 
val it : (string -> string) = <fun:it@2-1>
```

Is it possible to implement my own functions that have this property?

For example, could I design a function that matches strings with variable components:

```ml
matchPath "/products/:string/:string" (fun (category : string) (sku : string) -> ())

matchPath "/tickets/:int" (fun (id : int) -> ())
```

Ideally, I would like to do avoid dynamic casts.

Comment: Look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/printf.stringformat%5b%27t%2c%27result%5d-type-abbreviation-%5bfsharp%5d

Comment: I think it's due to [inline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/inline-functions) that is used in `doPrintf` that is called from [sprintf](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/24c798bfcee5d6f91ae2c19888baeb9946744c3a/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/printf.fs#L1582)

Comment: You might want to look at how type providers works in F# as well.

Comment: Forgot the link and SO don't let me edit the comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/type-providers/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two relevant F# features that make it possible to do something like this.

**Printf format strings**. The compiler handles format strings like `"hi %s"` in a special way. They are not limited just to `printf` and it's possible to use those in your library in a somewhat different way. This does not let you change the syntax, but if you were happy to specify your paths using e.g. `"/products/%s/%d"`, then you could use this. The Giraffe library defines [`routef` function](https://github.com/giraffe-fsharp/Giraffe/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md#routef), which uses this trick for request routing:

```
let webApp =
    choose [
        routef "/foo/%s/%s/%i" fooHandler
        routef "/bar/%O" (fun guid -> text (guid.ToString()))
    ]
```

**Type providers**. Another option is to use F# type providers. With parameterized type providers, you can write a type that is parameterized by a literal string and has members with types that are generated by some F# code you write based on the literal string parameter. An example is the [Regex type provider](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Text.RegexProvider/):

```
type TempRegex = Regex< @"^(?<Temperature>[\d\.]+)\s*°C$", noMethodPrefix = true >
TempRegex().Match("21.3°C").Temperature.TryValue
```

Here, the regular expression on the first line is static parameter of the `Regex` type provider. The type provider generates a `Match` method which returns an object with properties like `Temperature` that are based on the literal string. You would likely be able to use this and write something like:

```
MatchPath<"/products/:category/:sku">.Match(fun r -> 
  printfn "Got category %s and sku %s" r.Category r.Sku)
```

I tweaked your example so that `r` is an object with properties that have names matching to those in the string, but you could use a lambda with multiple parameters too. Although, if you wanted to specify types of those matches, you might need a fancier syntax like `"/product/[category:int]/[sku:string]"` - this is just a string you have to parse in the type provider, so it's completely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

1st: [Tomas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59274966/1901532)  is the right answer.

But ... I had the same question.
And while I could understand it conceptually as "it has to be 'the string format thing' or 'the provider stuff'"
I could not tell my self that I got until I tried an implementation
... And it took me a bit .
I used FSharp.Core's [printfs](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/printf.fs) and Giraffe's [FormatExpressions.fs](https://github.com/giraffe-fsharp/Giraffe/blob/master/src/Giraffe/FormatExpressions.fs) as guidelines
And came up with this naive gist/implementation, inspired by Giraffe  [FormatExpressions.fs](https://github.com/giraffe-fsharp/Giraffe/blob/master/src/Giraffe/FormatExpressions.fs)

BTW The trick is in this bit of magic  `fun (format: PrintfFormat<_, _, _, _, 'T>) (handle: 'T -> 'R)`

```ml
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

// convert format pattern to Regex Pattern
let rec toRegexPattern =
    function
    | '%' :: c :: tail ->
        match c with
        | 'i' ->
            let x, rest = toRegexPattern tail
            "(\d+)" + x, rest
        | 's' ->
            let x, rest = toRegexPattern tail
            "(\w+)" + x, rest
        | x ->
            failwithf "'%%%c' is Not Implemented\n" x
    | c :: tail ->
        let x, rest = toRegexPattern tail
        let r = c.ToString() |> Regex.Escape
        r + x, rest
    | [] -> "", []

// Handler Factory
let inline Handler (format: PrintfFormat<_, _, _, _, 'T>) (handle: 'T -> string) (decode: string list -> 'T) =
    format.Value.ToCharArray()
    |> List.ofArray
    |> toRegexPattern
    |> fst, handle, decode

// Active Patterns
let (|RegexMatch|_|) pattern input =
    let m = Regex.Match(input, pattern)
    if m.Success then
        let values =
            [ for g in Regex(pattern).Match(input).Groups do
                  if g.Success && g.Name <> "0" then yield g.Value ]
        Some values
    else
        None

let getPattern (pattern, _, _) = pattern
let gethandler (_, handle, _) = handle
let getDecoder (_, _, decode) = decode

let Router path =   
    let route1 =
        Handler "/xyz/%s/%i" 
            (fun (category, id) ->
                // process request
                sprintf "handled: route1: %s/%i" category id) 
            (fun values ->
                // convert matches
                values |> List.item 0,
                values
                |> List.item 1
                |> int32)
    let route2 =
        Handler "/xyz/%i" 
            (fun (id) -> sprintf "handled: route2: id: %i"  id) // handle
            (fun values -> values|> List.head |> int32) // decode 
    // Router
    (match path with
     | RegexMatch (getPattern route2) values ->
         values
         |> getDecoder route2
         |> gethandler route2
     | RegexMatch (getPattern route1) values ->
         values
         |> getDecoder route1
         |> gethandler route1
     | _ -> failwith "No Match")
    |> printf "routed: %A\n"

let main argv =
    try         
        let arg =  argv |> Array.skip 1 |> Array.head
        Router arg
        0 // return an integer exit code
    with
    | Failure msg -> 
        eprintf "Error: %s\n" msg
        -1
```